# Trying to load a PowerShell module from a custom path

Tags: powershell

We have a few modules residing on an SMB file share. We want to extend the module path where PowerShell looks for scripts (temporarily, not permanently).

By default, the contents of `$env:PSModulePath` environment variable is this:

```bsh
> $env:PSModulePath -split ';'

C:\Users\xxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Monitoring Agent\Agent\PowerShell\
```

As [documented by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/modifying-the-psmodulepath-installation-path?view=powershell-7), I wanted to extend this environment variable by one or more locations, so that calling the `Import-Module` or even a `#Required` header would work.

Thus, I executed the following commands:

```bsh
$customModulePaths = @('\\myServer\myShare\subfolder\module1\',
                       '\\myServer\myShare\subfolder\module2\')

$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator + $($customModulePaths -join [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator)
```

The scripts themselves are:

- `\\myServer\myShare\subfolder\module1\module1.psm1`
- `\\myServer\myShare\subfolder\module2\module2.psm1`

The module name is the same as the parent folder, and they have a manifest file (`.psd1)`.
I verified that the environment variable was indeed modified by checking the first command again.

Next, I executed `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Refresh`, expecting to see the 2 modules appear. However, the command's output only references items located in the original `$env:PSModulePath`'s folders. Executing `Import-Module module1` also results in an error, stating that the module can't be found.

Am I missing something or is what I'm trying to do not possible? Or is it due to the fact that I'm using UNC instead of local paths?

Comment: is there a corresponding module manifest for each module as well (ie. `\\myServer\myShare\subfolder\module1\module1.psd1`)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes (noted halfway), they each have a manifest generated using `New-ModuleManifest`.

Comment: Can the modules be imported successfully with `Import-Module \\myServer\myShare\subfolder\module1` and `Import-Module \\myServer\myShare\subfolder\module2`?

Comment: Yes, both can be imported when referencing the module folder (both the statements are successful)

Comment: @ƘɌỈSƬƠƑ I see the problem now. You need to include ```\\myServer\myShare\subfolder```, not the individual module folders

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you, that was exactly the issue! So simple in retrospect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the module paths already in `$env:PSModulePath` - notice that there are no actual module folders - only root folders that *contain* module folders.

Add the parent of the module directories instead and it should work:

```
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath,'\\myServer\myShare\subfolder' -join [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator
```